# Texture Mapping Distortion

Tags: texturing

I am working on a character creation pipeline, and the mesh's texture coordinate mapping seems to have become distorted.

I have attached an image of what is happening.  You can see that a checker board texture is being distorted and noisy in certain areas.
[image: Texture mapping Issue]

Contrast this with 'correct' character's texture mapping, where the texture mapping is not distorted at all.

[image]

Note that these two meshes have the exact same topology and exact same Vertex Order. I have confirmed vertex indices are the same between the 'correct' and 'incorrect' meshes.

I have also compared Face Order, and both have the same faces indices in same area, as shown below:
[image]

[image]

Note also that while troubleshooting, I assumed this was a UV issue and deleted the UVs from the mesh, and then copied the UV Map from the 'correct' mesh using Ctrl+L and 'Copy UV Maps'.  This had no effect on the issue.  I also deleted the UV then transferred UV map using Data Transfer modifier, and that had no effect either. Issue persists.

Edit: in response to comments, note the following

- The two overlapping meshes are not both visible at the same time in
  viewport in the screenshots posted. Thus, it is not an issue of overlapping and intersecting meshes.
- I have compared both UV's, they are perfectly identical and
  overlapping.  A selection of faces on one mesh appears in the same location of UV in UV Editor or the other mesh. As per below: (synching between viewport and UV Editor selection is on)

This is the mesh with "Correct" texture
[image: Correct]
This is the mesh with the "faulty" texture
[image: Faulty]

Comment: So when you compare the UV Editors they have the exact same UVs?

Comment: @femacamps Isn't it just you have two overlapping meshes in a Viewport?

Comment: I updated the main text to address those questions.  
UV's are identical.
Meshes are not overlapping in viewport.

Comment: Please share your issued  model (half face could be enough) via https://blend-exchange.com to speed up solving your Q. Thank you

Comment: I can't upload to blend-exchange since file is minimum 70MB, but i uploaded to Google Drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Fioa0CBswJLvtiZvYU0PJKRMJPLRmy2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I no longer need assistance with this issue.  I have just set my characters up from scratch and now UV mapping is correct, so can disregard this question.  Obviously issue remains unresolved, but I personally do not need a response to this.